# Adding new documents to production Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch cluster is constantly used by search queries. Once a week i get a batch of new documents i need to add to index. If i add them to index it will greatly slower search speeds while indexing and merging or moving shards.
What is the best way to avoid slowdown?

My solution so far:

```
1. Spin up a single node empty elastic.
2. Restore index i need to update from a snapshot.
3. Add new documents to this index.
4. Force merge shards
5. Snapshot resulting index.
6. Restore updated index on production cluster.
7. Update aliases to use updated index and delete old index.
```

I'm thinking restoring from snapshot shouldn't take much resources. Probably need to warm up restored index for better performance.

Is it normal solution or too complicated?

May be Elasticsearch has proper ways for adding documents without downtime or cluster slowdown?

Comment: How do you define "slowdown"? What's your reference benchmark? Can you tell a bit more about your setup?

Comment: Well "slowdown" is mildly said, i cant run _count request on index in process of adding new documents, not even saying running complicated queries. Probably indexing speed is too fast. But still changing index while it is used is bad idea to me.

Comment: What's your setup? Volume of data, etc?

Comment: 10 node cluster (1 is coordinating). Total 900Gb RAM, 160 CPU cores, 5Tb total index size (each index about 50-500Gb)

Comment: 10 nodes for 5TB is ample enough... but 500GB indexes? How many primary/replica shards?

Comment: 1 primary and 1 replica. Yea some indexes get updates more often, so they grow faster over time

Answer (score 0):

500GB on one primary shard, I would clearly fix this before doing anything else. You have 10 nodes so you need to spread the load over all of them. Adding nodes will not help at all.

The [official recommendation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/size-your-shards.html#shard-size-recommendation) is to not let shards grow bigger than 10/50GB. So in your case I would [split that index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-split-index.html) to have 10 primary shards (+1 replica each), so that each node can handle a part of the job. Otherwise, there's always only one node doing the write job and two nodes doing the read job, which is not optimal.

So before coming up with a way to circumvent the issue, fix the issue as I described above. Your cluster will be much better off, because 10 nodes should definitely handle 5TB easily without having to resort to a complex update procedure as the one you listed.

Try it out...

Comment: Sorry i misread your question about shards, thought u were asking how many replicas for each index. I'm trying to have shards around 20Gb size. Again overall performance is ok, problem is when i need to update those indexes.